# Check if user is verified with firebase android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, verification

I am writing a program where a user gets an email to verify their account. 
They then can login. The problem that I am encountering is that when the user logins in it doesn't check if the account is verified, it only checks if that account is a valid account in the firesbase auth database or whatever you call it but doesn't check if it also is a verified account. So I guess I'm asking how do I make it check if the user is also a verified user. Here is my could for the login class:

https://pastebin.com/T0DQC1GD

Answer (score 4):

You have [FirebaseUser.isEmailVerified()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/UserInfo#isEmailVerified()) which does **exactly** what you want.